# How should I grow a Bower Vine, especially in a climate that gets hot in the summer?

Tags: vines, hot-weather

Bower Vines are on sale at Home depot. I can't seem to find info on this vine when I google around. I was thinking of buying them all and trying to get them to start covering our fence.

It's in the 90's in Colorado and I'm wondering if anybody has had any experience with this species or knows what my chances are of getting these to grow during the summer months.

Comment: pssssttt!  Check out hops!  Golden hops for a vine to cover your fence.  Depending on where you live, this dies out above ground every winter.  Easy easy to clean off to protect your wood from damage.  The next spring watch out!  Do not stand too close or you might be ABSORBED...grins.  This is the best vine for fast complete coverage easy cleanup and care bar none.  In one month your fence will be covered.

Comment: Just posted a picture of my goldenhops....it is completely pulled off the arbor and cut down early early spring or even fall works.  This is within a month of growth maybe less.  We also harvested the flowers for beer.  Never made any but could have...

Answer (score 4):

[Pandorea jasminoides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandorea_jasminoides) is its real name - an evergreen twining climber with fragrant flowers in spring and summer, but it is not hardy unless your winter temperatures do not fall below 15°C, which I think is about 60°F. Ultimate height, where it survives, 4-8 metres by 1-1.5 metres wide. Pruning, if necessary, should be carried out after it has flowered. More info here https://www.shootgardening.co.uk/plant/pandorea-jasminoides-charisma - it mentions a specific variety of Pandorea, but the cultivation details are the same for all.

Answer (score 1):

[image: my golden hops vine]  This is in zone 4-5, Pacific NW. Mid June? The flowers are these adorable little japanese lantern looking things with pink/purple/green...like dried flowers.  This is one of the best vines I've ever grown for the purposes you are considering.  No diseases, insect problems after 7 years? Truly, don't stand too near!  3' per day is average...

Comment: I have measured the growth.  3' per day is real.  Maybe not every day...granted.  I only tested a couple of times.  But 3' a day I recorded mesef!  This plant grew from zero inches to over 27 feet by the end of June.  Covered the trees, the fence and was well on it's way across the dang two lane with a median road on the other side of the fence...and the sidewalk and 6' chunk of landscaping in between.  Not to mention the 8' arbor it completely covered before it went across the gap to the trees and that's where we started.  I am not kidding.  Amazing plant.  Totally covered that palm as well.